# Postgres/PostGIS GUI aplication development tools

Tags: windows, software-development, web-development, gui, postgresql

I am planning to use Postgres/postgis RDBMS on Windows platform 64bit for creating some user-friendly desktop or web application for populating a database, and I need a form designer tool like Filemaker (which is easy to build an application), but, unfortunately, doesn't work with PostgreSQL.

Is there any development tool to work with PostgreSQL? I am not a coder, I need some drag and drop tools.

Functionalities needed are:

- read and write data to database
- design forms field with different datatype
- drop down menus
- reading and inserting images into a database.

Comment: this is exactly what I've been looking for as well.. I can't believe that there's no simple answer to this. Can anybody help out?

Answer (score 1):

I hate paying for software, so when I do, I make sure there isn't anything free that can do the job. In the case of PostgreSQL, a lot of free software exists that claim they are GUI but for a simple task of creating a table, you need to know the Syntax of SQL. My favorite which is great for MySQL is HeidiSQL has an experimental version for Postgres. The reason why they call is "experimental" is if you specify the name of a database (or at least for me), it will not even load that database for you to create/edit/remove columns or even entries. After a little more searching, the one that I've found works the best is an application called DataGrip from JetBrains.

DataGrip is awesome. It works with almost every database structure you can think of including PostgreSQL. It allows you to easily create databases, tables, columns, and entries without knowing any SQL at all. It is very user-friendly and is compatible with Windows, OS X, and Linux. You can even create a table and get the creation SQL code for it. With this application, you will easily be able to:

- read and write data to database
- design forms field with different datatype (assuming you are talking about columns)
- reading and inserting images into a database. (You can turn the image into data through something like base64 format)

I don't really know what you mean by drop down menus but there are those in the application itself. It's free for students and open source projects - see their license for more information regarding that.

## [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) ([commercial](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/buy/))

> DataGrip is a database IDE from JetBrains that is tailored to suit
> specific needs of professional SQL developers and DBAs.
>
> Intelligent query console Allows you to execute queries in different
> modes and provides local history that keeps track of all your activity
> and protects you from losing your work.
>
> Efficient schema navigation Lets you jump to any table, view, or
> procedure by its name via corresponding action, or directly from its
> usages in the SQL code.
>
> Explain plan Gives you an extended insight into how your queries work
> and into database engine behavior so you can make your queries more
> efficient.
>
> Supported database servers / schemes: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle
> Database, PostgreSQL, SQLite, HyperSQL, Sybase, IBM DB2, H2
>
> [image: application screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) is a [framework](https://vaadin.com/framework) for writing user-interfaces for web apps in pure Java while automatically converting to standard web technologies in the client web browser. So no need to know HTTP, HTML, CSS, SASS, DOM, JavaScript, etc. All you need to know is [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), and let Vaadin handle translating your app to the web.

Your web actually runs on the server while presenting to the user via their browser. So the web app on your server is what actually connects to your Postgres server. Data appears on the web client, but the web client does not actually have access to the database.

Version 8 of Vaadin further simplifies [their data model](https://vaadin.com/docs8/-/part8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-overview.html) for binding to a database.

Vaadin offers a full set of widgets for building business-oriented web apps, including a powerful and flexible data grid: [Grid](https://vaadin.com/grid).

Personally, I find writing a UI programmatically to be easy enough with Vaadin. But they do offer a visual UI-builder tool, [*Vaadin Designer*](https://vaadin.com/designer).

You would use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) to connect your Java code in Vaadin with your Postgres server. Perhaps [the classic one](https://jdbc.postgresql.org) or [this next-generation one](https://github.com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng), or others.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [WaveMaker Rapid](https://www.wavemaker.com/rapid) too. It is a low-code tool that supports PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle and MS SQL Server. You can import the database objects or build your own schema and then generate CRUD forms automatically.

Comment: This is very good, but it cost, si there any desktop application like this one?